# Populate a 2D Array by a rule

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

How do I populate an array like this:

> 1 2 3 4
>   2 3 4 3
>   3 4 3 2
>   4 3 2 1

I need to find out a formula that determines the pattern of populating this array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4

int main()
{
int i,j,arr[N][N];
int a=1;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        arr[j][i]=i+j+1;
    }
for(i=0; i < N; i++)

    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        printf("%2i ",arr[j][i]);
        printf("\n"); 


 return 0;
}
```

It prints out similarly to the desired array except that I need "3" at the end of the second row, and after that point, it goes reversed. Please, explain me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    arr[j][i]=N-abs(i+j-(N-1));
```

`abs()` can be used any time you need a numerical sequence which is mirrored around some value. You just need to subtract a constant such that the value you want to mirror around is zero, take the absolute, and then re-adjust the output.

In your case (with N = 4) the `(i+j)` summation produces: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. The middle value is N-1, as the largest value is 2 * (N-1).

Subtracting N-1 (3) gives: -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3.

The `abs()` gives: 3,2,1,0,1,2,3.

If we subtract that from N (4) we get the desired 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[j][i]=(j * 3 + j/ 3 + b) % N + 1;
```